# IndexError: too many indices for array python

Tags: python, indexing

My problem is get all element from an array except the first element.
I use the objects p and q.

```
 print(p.p)
 print(q.p)
```

The output is :

> (79, 12.37, 1.63, 2.3, 24.5, 88., 2.22, 2.45, 0.4, 1.9, 2.12, 0.89, 2.78, 342.)
>
> (29, 12.33, 0.99, 1.95, 14.8, 136., 1.9, 1.85, 0.35, 2.76, 3.4, 1.06, 2.31, 750.)

If I try this :

```
 x = p.p[1:]
 y = q.p[1:]
```

I receive this error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

I think I have this error because if I try:

```
print(p.p(shape))
```

The output is:

> ()

How can I solve this problem ?

Update:

```
class Point:

def __init__(self, p):
    self.p = p #numpy
    self.NN = [] 
    self.active = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `for` loop with the index variable starting at 1:

```
for i in range(1, p.size):
    print(p[i])
```

Comment: Doesn't work,AttributeError: 'numpy.void' object has no attribute 'length'

Comment: use `p.size` instead

Comment: I tried but doesn't work, in fact if I print (p.p.size) , the result is 1

Comment: what is the story behind p.p? what you don't simply use p?

Comment: Because p is an object and the value that I want is in p.p

Comment: p is numpy object? can you provide your entire code?

Comment: Yes is numpy object, p is a simple object with some fields and one of this is a numpy object, the code is too long

Comment: just send this object by editing your qustion and add an update section!